# How to build CalDAV Server - change IP

Tags: networking, server, thunderbird, calendar

I try to build a CalDAV Server on my server with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. I have a real IP (configured in Ubuntu) but I don't no how to configure the CalDAV Server.

I was following [this instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/822818/calendar-server) but i don't know how to change my IP localhost to real IP to be able to use it in Mozilla Thunderbird Lightning (Windows).

Could you share with me step by step to create the CalDAV Server using [Radicale](https://github.com/Kozea/Radicale/wiki/Simple-installation).

Thank You!

Comment: Maybe you will get answers here: https://github.com/Kozea/Radicale/wiki/Simple-installation.

Comment: ##### Open config file for editing ServerUSER@Server:~$ sudo nano /etc/radicale/config ##### Add these lines under relevant portions of [server] section where your router is 192.168.1.1 hosts = 0.0.0.0:5232 ##### By setting ssl = True, Radicale no longer responds to HTTP requests. ssl = True certificate = /etc/ssl/radicale.cert.pem key = /etc/ssl/radicale.key.pem

this line it means im must change IP from hosts = 0.0.0.0:5232 > 203.xxx.xxx.xxx:5232 (Real IP) right?